# Syntax needed for adding constraints to fields

Tags: sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server, I want to alter a field to "NOT NULL" AND DEFAULT ''.
I've already issued the following two commands:

```
ALTER TABLE USR ADD Country Varchar(128)
UPDATE USR SET Country=''
```

Now I need

```
1. ALTER TABLE USR ADD CONSTRAINT CountryIsNotNull something
2. ALTER TABLE USR ADD CONSTRAINT CountryDefault default ''
```

Comment: What manual?  Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to google it however here is the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE USR
ALTER COLUMN Country varchar(128) NOT NULL 
go
ALTER TABLE USR
ADD CONSTRAINT df_usr_conuntry_default DEFAULT '' for Country
go
```

You could have done the whole thing in one line though with the following:

```
alter table USR 
add Country varchar(128) not null default '' with values
```

Comment: Thanks!  In your second example, the word column needs to be removed.

Comment: thanks, did not run it but the sql syntax checker actually let it through on my box.  removed it.